# How am I able to pass/store the variable (sFolder) from the CommandButton1_Click to the Commandbutton2_Click?

Tags: excel, vba, call, commandbutton

The `"sFolder"` variable is not displaying on the `CommandButton2_Click()` after being established by `CommanButton1_Click()`.

I've tried calling different subs and passing variables around but I can't get the right combination.

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim sFolder As Variant
If sFolder = "" Then
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Title = "Select a Folder"
    If .Show = -1 Then
        sFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
    End If
End With
End Sub

Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Debug.Print sFolder
End Sub
```

I want the second button to print  the file name I select however it is blank with no errors.

Comment: You want to declare `sFolder` with a larger [scope](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/141693/scope-of-variables-in-visual-basic-for-applications), probably at the Module level. Bear in mind that your second sub will return Nothing if you have not yet assigned a value to `sFolder`

Answer (score 0):

It isn't *blank*, it's `Variant/Empty`, which is the variant subtype you get for any uninitialized/undeclared local variable - something `Option Explicit` would prevent, by forcing you to declare the variables you're using.

`sFolder` only exists in the *scope* of the `CommandButton1_Click` procedure: it is undefined in the scope of `CommandButton2_Click` (or anywhere else).

Specify `Option Explicit` at the top of the module, and promote that `sFolder` variable from a local variable up to a *module variable* (remove the `Dim sFolder As Variant` declaration from the button1 click handler), so that it is now usable in every procedure of that module:

```
Option Explicit
Private sFolder As Variant
```

Now if you click button2 first, you'll still get an empty string (for the string representation of `Variant/Empty` is an empty string), but you'll see the value in the immediate pane if you click button2 after clicking button1.

Answer (score 0):

Make the variable available to any sub procedure within that worksheet's code sheet.

```
Option Explicit

Private sFolder As Variant

Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    If sFolder = "" Then
        With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
            .Title = "Select a Folder"
            If .Show = -1 Then
                sFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
            End If
        End With
    End If

End Sub

Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Debug.Print sFolder
End Sub
```